# Left click detection sporadic

Tags: 14.04, mouse

Woke up this morning to find ubuntu not detecting left-clicks. Tested on two mice, same behavior. It was maybe registering 1 out of every 15 or so. I reinstalled all the packages that had "mouse" or "input" in the name, and the behavior seemed to improve. The side panel and desktop were both "clickable" and I could click most things in Chrome except the location bar and the tabs. After a short window of functionality, it has started to become more intermittent. Much of the time clicks work, but every once in a while they stop for 5-10 seconds. At this point I usually start clicking somewhere else, and when I go back clicks work again.

Running xinput query-state verifies that even when holding the left mouse button down, xinput sometimes registers it as up.

Searching finds a few cases of this happening, and even one with 14.04, but no solutions. Is there something else I can try reinstalling?

Update: Clicking on the desktop is never registered. After clicking on the desktop and going back to Chrome, clicks are not registered until I move the window. Once I move the window, all clicks are registered. I have replicated this at least 10 times, including after a restart.

Comment: I went through reinstalling packages again, and I *believe* I missed xinput on the first go. Reinstalling this and restarting seems to have made things a lot better. There are still some missed clicks, but 97% seem to work fine. I have tried it on various window elements and all seem to (eventually) work.

Answer (score 0):

I took the nuclear option and ran this script

```
#!/bin/bash

for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '(dpkg|apt|mysql|mythtv)'` ; do apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
```

It goes through everything installed and reinstalls it. Mouse works now.